# Windows XP SP3 Task Scheduler Error 0x80070005

Tags: windows-xp, task-scheduler

When I try to add a task I get error: Error 0X80070005: Access Is Denied

Windows XP Pro Service Pack 3.
1 administrator account with no password!
I don't want to set password for the account because I want auto login when i start computer without entering any passwords.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft say this problem is caused by security update 841873

There is a hotfix available.

See: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/904423

Comment: Do I need to request microsoft for this fix? There is no direct download

Comment: I've downloaded the fix, it told me that my service pack (3) is newer, and the fix is not needed so I couldn't install it anyway.

Comment: Have you checked whether you have 841873 installed? If so, remove it and then continue troubleshooting.

Comment: it's not installed